# Next Js , why the kittens are not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

As in the Next Js docs described i added a next.config.js file to tell Next js that i want to load kittens into my app.

This is the ressource:

https://placekitten.com/640/360

The next.config.js looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ["placekitten.com"],
  },
};
```

in my component i t looks like this:

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
export default function SidebarItem({
  categories = [
    "Get the Look",
    "Clothing",
    "Shoes",
    "Sports",
  ],
}) {
  return (
    <section className='flex'>
      <Image
        alt='Picture of the author'
        width={300}
        height={300}
        src='/640/360'
      />
    </section>
  );
}
```

I get this error:
image:1 GET http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=%2F640%2F360&w=640&q=75 400 (Bad Request)

What im doing wrong?

Comment: try using a loader instead https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader as that kitten site won't implement the params passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set full path to the image:

```
<Image
   alt='Picture of the author'
   width={300}
   height={300}
   src='https://placekitten.com/640/360'
/>
```